# Debian Router Configuration Problem

Tags: debian, iptables, dhcp, hostapd

I just got my brand new laptop and I intet to make the old one to act as a home router, just to play and learn a bit about Networking.
After I fallow some tutorials, I make the configuration as fallow:

-Debian Buster Lite

-isc-dhcp-server

-hostapd

-Iptables

My configurations are:

```
# dhcpd.conf
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd
#


default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;



    subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.42.10 192.168.42.50;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.42.255;
        option routers 192.168.42.1;
        default-lease-time 600;
        max-lease-time 7200;
        option domain-name "local";
        option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
    }

subnet 192.168.11.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        range 192.168.11.10 192.168.11.50;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.11.255;
        option routers 192.168.11.1;
        default-lease-time 600;
        max-lease-time 7200;
        option domain-name "local";
        option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
    }
```

INTERFACE CONFIGURATION

```
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
        allow-hotplug wlan0
#       post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules


iface wlan0 inet static
      address 192.168.42.1
      netmask 255.255.255.0

#LAN Port

auto iface eth1

iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.11.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0

dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

HOSTAPD CONFIG

```
interface=wlan0
#driver=rtl871xdrv
ssid=SuperWifi
country_code=GB
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=$3cre7P@$$w0rd
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_group_rekey=86400
ieee80211n=1
wme_enabled=1
```

IP TABLES

```
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Mon Sep  2 14:40:14 2019
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state -i eth1 --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state -i wlan0 --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state -i eth0 -o eth1 --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state -i eth0 -o wlan0 --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep  2 14:40:14 2019
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Mon Sep  2 14:40:14 2019
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep  2 14:40:14 2019
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Mon Sep  2 14:40:14 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep  2 14:40:14 2019
```

Interesting fact is when I ENABLE the IP tables , everything works perfect into the network BUT the laptop itself (where I host the server) have no internet connection.

When I DISABLE the iptables the laptop have internet but not the clients. 
How can I allow the laptop where i host the server to be able to connect to the internet?

Basically I`m trying to create a TOR router but on a laptop and I need the server to be able to communicate on the internet before I try anything else.

AS REQUESTED 
My output of `ip route` when IPTABLES are ACTIVE

```
me@router:~ $ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.13 
192.168.11.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.11.1 linkdown 
192.168.42.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.1
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ip route` when the firewall rules are active?

Answer (score 0):

Through what I see, it seems you did not set the routing option to 1.
You can check it with : `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

If the result is 0, it is off. You can change it directly to your running system with :`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Then to make it mandatory, edit /etc/sysctl.conf file and uncomment the line showing `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Comment: my return is 1. Is activated.